# Is there a "special" syntax for adding styles to children of a React Native component?

Tags: react-native

So, in regular CSS, if I want to apply a style to all children of elements with a given id/class/element name, I would do this:

```
(id/class/name of parent element) * {

}
```

This will automatically apply to every child of the specified parent element(s) - I don't need to add any classes/ids/names, etc. to the children.

Is there an equivalent syntax in React Native? Best I can do so far is

```
view {
// style here
}
subelementsOfView {

}
```

and then add the subelementsOfView style to all children of View.

Am I wrong? Is there another syntax I can use?

Comment: You would create a global style file with StyleSheet , then extend it to the children and link style to the corresponding global style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a StyleSheet as shown:

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   someStyleKey: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
   }
})
```

Wherever your children components are you can do the following:

```
import { styles } from '../<location-of-stylesheet>'

// Using View as an example component
<View style={styles.someStyleKey}></View>
```

If your child component already has a style you can also pass in an array of styles such as:

```
<View style={[existingStyle, styles.someStyleKey]}></View>
```

Whatever comes later in the style array will overwrite previous style values.

Comment: Is the View a parent or child?

Comment: @moonman239 It applies for either.  I don't have any of your code above from the RN side so its hard to say exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  But that is how you would apply styles to any component in React ecosystem.

Can you give some more code as to exactly what your use case looks like?

Comment: So, when I asked the question, I knew about that syntax, but I wanted to know if there was a different syntax I could use that would automatically apply to a component's children. I've since updated my question's title

Comment: @moonman239 Understood.  I don't think there is in the same way you mention above.  The closest would be creating a universal style to just add to each components `style` prop.  I could be wrong though so I'm curious to see what other responses people might have.